# JSON.dump on any ActiveRecord object fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I've got a project running Rails 3.1.3 and JSON gem 1.6.3, and am unable to pass any ActiveRecord instance to JSON.dump. I always get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for #<JSON::Ext::Generator::State:0x000001033f2088>
from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@project/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/serialization.rb:10:in `serializable_hash'
from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@project/gems/activemodel-3.1.3/lib/active_model/serializers/json.rb:84:in `as_json'
from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@project/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:47:in `block in encode'
from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@project/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:78:in `check_for_circular_references'
from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@project/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:46:in `encode'
from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@project/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:31:in `encode'
from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@project/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb:20:in `to_json'
from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@project/gems/json-1.6.3/lib/json/common.rb:216:in `generate'
from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@project/gems/json-1.6.3/lib/json/common.rb:216:in `generate'
from /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@project/gems/json-1.6.3/lib/json/common.rb:380:in `dump'
```

Passing JSON.dump a hash, an instance of a non-ActiveRecord class, etc. work fine, and #to_json works on my ActiveRecord instances. I can't just call #to_json instead, though, as it is actually a library I'm passing my ActiveRecord object to that calls JSON.dump. However I have the same problem skipping that other library altogether and just calling JSON.dump myself.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the links below, it sounds like there's an issue with JSON overriding to_json with its own encoding.

- https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4925-rails-3-to_json-incompatible-with-json-core-library
- https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4494-ruby-192-heads-json-support-breaks-to_json-for-arrays-of-records
- https://github.com/defunkt/resque/issues/149

The workaround that popped up in the threads a few times was to put the following code into your environments.rb file.

```
class Array
  def to_json(*a)
    ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(self)
  end
end
```